# R grid : 'grob' path must contain at least one name 'grob'

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I want to add an arrow to a ggplot2 graph. I keep getting an error: 'grob' path must contain at least one name 'grob'.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

#create a plot
grid.newpage()
update_geom_defaults("smooth", aes(color="black"))
print(
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method=lm)

)

#list views
current.vpTree()

# change the view
downViewport("panel.6-4-6-4")

# add an arrow
sline <- grid.get(gPath("smooth", "polyline"),
                  grep=TRUE)
grid.segments(.7, .8, 
              grobX(sline, 45), grobY(sline, 45),
              arrow=arrow(angle=10, type="closed"),
              gp=gpar(fill="black"))
```

Comment: maybe need a wee `grid.force()` in there (before the `grid.get`)

Comment: that actually worked